# Getting error when import the modules in Angular

Tags: angular

Im getting error when import the module.
[codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxJ1i.png)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import employees from './data/employees.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'em-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.scss']
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
   
title:string="Employee management solution";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmcKr.png)

Comment: That’s a json file, not a module. What is inside?

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by adding following to `"resolveJsonModule": true` to **tsconfig.json** file. See [Stackblitz demo](https://angular-ivy-5c1vu9.stackblitz.io) for example